# Keeping the totals row always visible in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have data in rows 1:69 and created a totals row 70 that summarizes the above rows. How do I keep row 70 always visible? In the Sheets iOS app, I can freeze rows 1:69 and always see row 70, but in a desktop web browser I get the error message "The current window is too small to properly display the sheet. Consider resizing your browser window or Adjusting frozen rows and columns."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to move the totals to the very first row in the sheet, like this:

1. Click cell A1 and choose **Insert > Row above**.
2. Choose **View > Freeze > 1 row**.
3. Use cut (**Control-X**) and paste (**Control+V**) to move the summary formula cells from row 70 to row 1.

When the totals are at the top of the sheet, and the first row is in the frozen section, it will remain visible in the web version of Google Sheets as well as the Sheets iOS app.